# Difference between hours using moment

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I understand this is a popular question on the internet. But the point is that I need to do something accurately and as I'm not very familiar with working with dates, I needed to ask this question.

My problem is the following, from a timestamp I have to define certain actions. These actions are taken under the following conditions:

`Prep` - starts about an hour before timestamp;

`Run` - starts right at timestamp;

`Reset` - this action is taken if 15 minutes have passed after the timestamp;

Bearing in mind that the timestamp would be the following:

```js
const timestamp = "2021-11-16T09:18:02+0000"
```

I had the idea to do it this way:

```js
const time = moment(timestamp).diff(moment(), "minutes")
```

But to be honest I don't know how I can improve this. Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution I found suitable using momentjs

```js
const timestamp = "2021-11-16T09:18:02+0000"
const reset = moment(timestamp).add(15, 'minutes').format('LT')
const current = moment(timestamp).format('LT')
const prev = moment(timestamp).subtract(1, 'hour').format('LT')

console.log("Reset:",reset,"\nCurrent",current,"\nPrev",prev)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Which when logged out

`reset` 3:03 PM
`current` 2:48 PM
`prev` 1:48 PM

For More Regarding [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/)

Comment: No need to wrap moment in moment. I have updated your code and made a snippet

Answer (score 5):

No need for moment

this should help you get started

```js
const timestamp = "2021-11-16T09:18:02+0000"

const d = new Date(timestamp)

const prep = new Date(timestamp);
prep.setHours(prep.getHours()-1);// Prep - starts about an hour before timestamp;

// Run - starts right at timestamp;


const resetTime = new Date(timestamp)
// Reset - this action is taken if 15 minutes have passed after the timestamp;
resetTime.setMinutes(resetTime.getMinutes()-15)

console.log(d)
console.log(prep)
console.log(resetTime)

console.log((d.getTime()-prep.getTime())/60000)
```